# LyX + Biblatex => XHTML (for conversion to ODT)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx, html

I am writing a document in LyX (2.1.2) and need to share it for editing and review purposes with others who do not use LyX/LaTeX. I am also using Biblatex + Biber for the bibliography.

LyX's inbuilt converter to ODT fails to create a document, primarily because it barfs on the version of Biblatex that I have. Considering, that I do not want a picture perfect document, I tried the alternative:

1. Export the LyX document to XHTML (using the inbuilt converter). I get the document, but without the bibliography. The citations are all linked (with nice blue lines) that don't go anywhere :(

   (Note: Same issue with eLyXer. It also does not parse the bibliography. Biblatex support is still *pending*).
2. Use Xhtml2ODT to get a nice ODT file that I can then share.

So, the question is "How can I get my bibliography out?" An external program that could convert the `.bib` file to XHTML would be great. (Note: bib2xhtml does **not** work).

Any pointers? Or alternatively, a script that could move my Biblatex `.bib` to one than plain bibtex (and hence bib2xhtml) can parse?

Comment: try to export LyX document to LaTeX and convert it manually to `odt` with `latex filename; biber filename; mk4ht oolatex filename` it will probably fail in the last step, but you can post some detailed error messages from terminal here then